# SQL return date range even when count is null

Tags: sql, date, null

I am counting the total number of logins(`UsersID`) over the past 7 days. I do a count on the total number of users id's over this date range and group by date. My problem is that if there are no users id's logged for a date, then the date isn't displayed.

So I need to display 0 for dates where there have been no logins.

My code is:

```
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 101) +  ' 00:00.00';
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day,7, @StartDate);

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) as LoginDate, COUNT(UsersID) AS TotalForDay
FROM [STATS].[dbo].[UsersLogin]
WHERE [DateTime]>@StartDate 
AND [DateTime]<@EndDate
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])
ORDER BY LoginDate desc;
```

Comment: You could select the date range from dual (or whichever system is available) and take a left join with UsersLogin

Comment: Please post your RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc) so an appropriate solution can be offered.  Based on your syntax it seems to be **SQL Server**.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2800/sql-server-function-to-return-a-range-of-dates/

Comment: Thanks everyone, rs provided the correct solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a separate Table with date values, Try this

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 101) +  ' 00:00.00';
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day,7, @StartDate);
;with cte as
(
    select @startdate DateValue
    union all
    select DateValue + 1
    from    cte   
    where   DateValue + 1 < @enddate
)


select a.DateValue as LoginDate,  COUNT(UsersID) AS TotalForDay
from cte a
LEFT outer join [STATS].[dbo].[UsersLogin] b 
on CONVERT(varchar(15), a.DateValue,101) = CONVERT(varchar(15), b.[DateTime],101)
group by a.DateValue
order by a.DateValue desc
```

For grouping by hours:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 101) +  ' 00:00.00';
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day,7, @StartDate);
;with cte as
(
    select @startdate DateValue
    union all
    select DATEADD (hh,1,DateValue)
    from    cte   
    where   DATEADD (hh,1,DateValue) < @enddate
)


select a.DateValue as LoginDate,  COUNT(UsersID) AS TotalForDay
from cte a
LEFT outer join [STATS].[dbo].[UsersLogin] b 
on CONVERT(varchar(15), a.DateValue,101) = CONVERT(varchar(15), b.[DateTime],101)
group by a.DateValue
order by a.DateValue desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: How would I now go about grouping the UserID count on an hourly basis instead of daily/by date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PhilCoulter, use same query and change it to return date time with hours and group by that. Check my updated answer, remember to add maxrecursion 0

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a left join on date against a Calendar relation, whether implemented statically as a table or dynamically as a sub-query.

```
SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 101) +  ' 00:00.00';
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day,7, @StartDate);

SELECT C.Date, COUNT(UsersID) AS TotalForDay
FROM Calendar as C
LEFT JOIN [STATS].[dbo].[UsersLogin] as U on C.Date = CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])       
WHERE [DateTime]>@StartDate 
AND [DateTime]<@EndDate
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime])
ORDER BY LoginDate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If need more simple than use this.
Create a temporary table variable and add dates from start to end into that:

```
Declare @temp_Dates Table
(
  TempDate datetime
)

While (@StartDate<@EndDate)
Begin
  Insert Into @temp_Dates Select @EndDate
  Set @EndDate=DATEADD(DAY,-1,@EndDate)
End
```

After that take left join of your table with above one:

```
SELECT Cast(Convert(varchar(20),td.TempDate,101) as DateTime) as LoginDate,     COUNT(UsersID) AS TotalForDay
FROM @temp_Dates td
Left Join  UsersLogin ul On Cast(Convert(varchar(20),ul.DateTime,101) as     DateTime)=Cast(Convert(varchar(20),td.TempDate,101) as DateTime)
GROUP BY Cast(Convert(varchar(20),td.TempDate,101) as DateTime)
ORDER BY LoginDate desc
```

You will get your desired result.